# iOS Change Button Text on Presenting View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a pretty complicated setup in terms of view controllers. I have reasons for it that are kind of out of the scope of this question. So I have 3 view controllers.

ViewControllerA is the main view controller in this case. ViewControllerB is a container view controller that is displayed from ViewControllerA. ViewControllerB has a button that has a segue to display ViewControllerC. Then in ViewControllerC there is a button to dismiss to go back.

ViewController's A and B can be different. Depending on if the user is editing an object or creating a new object. The things I'm talking about remain constient between those two cases.

Basically my goal is when a user dismisses ViewControllerC it changes a button text on ViewControllerB. Depending on the users actions on ViewControllerC.

I was thinking about using `self.presentingViewController` somehow or something along those lines but I can't figure out how to access that specific button within ViewControllerB.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Comment: Use delegate to give a callback to viewcontroller b and update your button overthere.

Comment: @PrakashShaiva Any chance you could provide some example code? Not quite sure how I would implement this.

Comment: How are you moving back from C to B?  Are you unwinding a segue or just dismissing a presenting view controller?

Comment: @DavidShaw Checking to see if `self.navigationController != nil` if so `self.navigationController?.popViewController` else `dismiss`. Only using navigation controller on iPad currently for popover functionality.

Comment: Refer this link to know how to implement delegates http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-delegates

Comment: @PrakashShaiva Using Swift...

Comment: Here is the swift tutorial link https://medium.com/compileswift/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a protocol to define a common method to update button text. Both ViewControllerB's can then conform to this protocol. Then use a delegate callback approach to call these methods from your ViewControllerC.

When you present ViewControllerC from ViewControllerB you can set the `delegate` property to `self` before presenting it. You would do this in different places depending on how you are presenting ViewControllerC. As you said you're using a segue to do it, then you should do this in the `prepareForSegue` method.

1. Declare a `protocol` that defines a method to update the button's text like this:

> ```
> protocol ChangeableButtonTextViewController {
>     func updateButtonText(newText: String)
> }
> ```

Then make your EditViewControllerB and CreateViewControllerB conform to this protocol to update the button text:

> ```
> class EditViewControllerB: UIViewController, ChangeableButtonTextViewController {
>     func updateButtonText(newText: String) {
>         button.text = newText
>     }
>
>     // Other stuff in your ViewController
> }
> ```

2. Add a `delegate` property to ViewControllerC like this:

> `var delegate: ChangeableButtonTextViewController?`

3. Add a `prepareForSegue` method to EditViewControllerB and CreateViewControllerB which would look something like:

> ```
> override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
>       segue.destination as! ViewControllerC).delegate = self
> }
> ```

4. You can then do something like this in ViewControllerC:

> ```
> func dismiss() {
>     delegate.updateButtonText("NewText")
> }
> ```

Let me know if you need any further clarifications.

Comment: How would I define `delegate`?

Comment: So `delegate` could be defined like this: `weak var delegate: ViewControllerB?`

Comment: Ok so one problem with that. ViewControllerB has two different options. Like it could be EditViewControllerB or CreateViewControllerB. ViewControllerC is the same for both of those tho.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. Testing it now. One error so far, `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'ChangeableButtonTextViewController'`. Removing the `weak` fixed this tho.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad; `weak` would only work if `delegate` was of type `ViewControllerB` rather than something that conforms to a protocol. So yes, just remove `weak`  I've updated my answer to remove `weak`

Comment: This seems to work great!! Did end up changing `delegate.updateButtonText("NewText")` to `delegate?.updateButtonText(newText: "NewText")` just because of how it was setup. Totally learned something new today. Thank you very much for the detail and example code you provided. One of the better Stack Overflow answers I've seen in a while. Will up vote and accept now. Thank you very much.